# unable to delete listview

Tags: list-view

I am trying to delete a user's list views that they created. The user no longer wants the list view. I've logged in as the user via grant login access and I go to the list views and the only option is `clone` and `create new view`. Their profile has `Create and Customize List Views`. How can I delete the list views they created and don't want anymore? Is it not possible for a system administrator to delete a users list views when logged on as the user via grant login access? I cannot figure out a why to delete these list views? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to delete list views (even if they created them) the user needs

> Manage Public List Views

Permissions

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_del.htm

Comment: I've set that permission too to no avail? Not sure what is going on?

Comment: @Dman100 - I tried without that permission and was seeing what you were seeing. Then I enable that permission and it worked as was expected...Maybe you were editing the wrong profile?

Comment: I double checked and I'm editing the correct profile. When you enabled the permission and tried to delete the list view were you logged in as a different user via grant login access where that user had created the list view? I'm wondering if the user that created the list view has to delete it?

Comment: When I did it they had created the list view. BUT, they were able to delete any list view so that should not be the case. Are you sure the list view is not the standard list view? Maybe add some screen shots of what you are seeing as well as the list view definition. Also, can you see the list view when logged in as system admin? If they created it you should not be able to. If they can see it and you cannot then they created it

Comment: after a lot of digging I found the issue/resolution here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000182084&language=en_US

Comment: @Dman100 - Isn't that what I said, ensure the user you are logging in as has "Manage List Views" ???

Comment: No, it wasn't providing the "Mange List View" permission. It was editing/saving the existing list view and then the duplicate list view would then be removed. It was a known bug when sending over a list view in a change set.

Comment: @Dman100 - gotcha. Can you add that as an answer then and accept it. so others looking for a similar problem can find it in case the link goes dead

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the List View you are trying to Delete was created in Salesforce Classic. In order to Delete it, try switching from Lightning to Classic and then navigating back to that list view.